# How to display error message when an Ajax request doesn't succed?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

This action is being called by an ajax. I'd like to know how to capture the message went there in excepion.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult AjaxManage(ManageClassification model, string random)
    {
        if (model.Classification.ClassificationId == 0 &&
            !string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Classification.ClassificationName))
        {
           //
        }
        else
        {
             throw new Exception("Entity cannot be empty.");
        }
    }
```

How do I display the error back to the page?

```
 $.ajax({
            //...
            ,
            error:function(){
                //display error here ... 
            }
        });
```

how to capture and display the error message sent be the action located in the server? Once the message is captured, it will be displayed for the user to see what went wrong.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the steps here in order to display the error that was raised. It is for ASP.NET but should apply to MVC

http://encosia.com/use-jquery-to-catch-and-display-aspnet-ajax-service-errors/

You may also get some debugging information in the browser console

Comment: `var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");` and `alert(err.Message);` are throwing error.

Comment: It's doesn't work, i.e. it's not responsive when it get to that part of the code. I don't know what error is being thrown.

Comment: use console.log rather than the alert and check the console view in your browser developer tools

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) 
{
   alert(errorThrown);
   alert(textStatus);
}
```

Comment: **textStatus** is displaying the text `error` while **errorThrown** is displaying the text `undifined`